# Is PySpark rollback possible with parquet files

Tags: pyspark, data-science, bigdata, etl, parquet

I have an ETL pipeline implemented in pyspark. I have implemented change data capture (CDC). Source and destination both are Parquet format tables.

My ETL reads a set of tables from source, processes them and stores the same set of tables in destination with additional columns in a single script/step.

My use case is: Have a checkpoint in destination before I start script execution. If there is an error while processing any one of the tables, I want all the changes, for all tables in current run to be rolled back to the previous checkpoint.

Can this be achieved using pyspark? What should be the best way to achieve this?

Currently I am using Apache hudi just for failover mechanism. But I really don't want the overhead of Hudi just to implement this.

Comment: What about using Delta Lake format instead? It will give you transactionality, if operation fails, then changes aren't committed. And if you have multiple tables, you can revert all of them if necessary

Comment: Actually I am using Apache Hudi already. But wanted to know if this can be achieved without having more abstraction layer